# Making Bokeh CheckboxGroup have links as text

Tags: python, bokeh

How can I use [Bokeh Checkbox group](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#checkboxgroup), but instead of text, have links. For example, something like,

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup

output_file("checkbox_group.html")

checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(
        labels=[Link("Option 1"), "Option 2", "Option 3"], active=[0, 1])

show(checkbox_group)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no straightforward way of doing that.

I'd say that the most "correct" way would be to just create a custom Bokeh model that extends `CheckboxGroup`.

Alternatively, you can create checkboxes one by one manually and lay them out along with manually created links.